# Give multiple tags to docker image using one docker tag command

Tags: docker, tags

I know it's possible to give multiple tags to one image when you use `docker build`:

```
docker build -t name1:tag1 -t name1:tag2 -t name2 .
```

But we need to tag existing images. So we use `docker tag`.
Is it possible to give multiple tags to one image using one`docker tag` command?

Something like:

```
docker tag busybox:latest image:1.0,latest
```

Instead of reusing the command like here?:

```
docker tag busybox:latest image1:1.0
docker tag busybox:latest image1:latest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker multiple tags can be achieved using xargs utility.

Try this

`echo -e "image:latest\n image:1.0" | xargs -I{} docker tag busybox:latest {}`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of the `tag` command: No.

https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/client/image/tag.go